# While populating a list box with concatenated columns values from table, How to retrieve corresponding ID and pass the value onchange

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

Here is my drop-down select box with concatenated columns. How can I retrieve the ID of the record and pass that value onchange?

```
<asp:DropDownList 
    ID="DropDownList2" 
    runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" 
    DataTextField="Expr1" 
    DataValueField="Expr1">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:AccessDataSource 
    ID="AccessDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    DataFile="~/tools/tracker/Tracker.mdb" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT PAcronym + ' - ' + Milestone + ' (' + PRelease + ')' AS Expr1 FROM Projects ORDER BY PAcronym + ' - ' + Milestone + ' (' + PRelease + ')' ">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2):

Select the ID in your query, then `DataValueField="ID"`.  You'll then be able to access the value `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.  It'll be stored in `DropDownList2.SelectedValue`.